# Jquery template does not render a single item

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-templates

I am trying to experiment with the jquery template plugin.

I have a single template defined as this:

```
<script id="referentTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
<form id="referent-form" method="post" action="#">
<div class="fields">
    <input type="hidden" name="referentID" value="${ReferentID}" />
    <table>
        <tr><td><label for="firstName">First Name</label><br />
                <input type="text" name="firstName" value="${FirstName}" /></td>
            <td><label for="lastName">Last Name</label><br />
                <input type="text" name="lastName" value="${LastName}" /></td></tr>
        <tr><td><label for="fullName">Full Name</label><br />
                <input disabled="disabled" type="text" name="fullName" value="${FirstName} ${LastName}" /></td></tr>
        <tr><td><label for="phoneNumber">Telephone</label><br />
                <input type="text" name="phoneNumber" value="${PhoneNumber}" /></td>
            <td><label for="email">EMail</label><br />
                <input type="text" name="email" value="${Email}" /></td></tr>
    </table>
</div>
<div id="validation-message"></div>
<div style="text-align:right; padding: 8px 0px 0px 0px;">
    <input type="submit" id="btnSave" class="button" value="Save" />
    <input type="button" id="btnCancel" class="button" value="Cancel" />
</div>
</form>
</script>
```

I would like to load this template dinamically using the following code

```
$("#new-referent").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: baseUrl + 'MyService.asmx/New',
        data: JSON.stringify({}),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
            // Get the referent item from the webservice
            var referent = msg.d;
            // Render the template with the Referent data
            var referentTemplate = $("#referentTemplate").tmpl(referent);
            //Show the Dialog
            $("#referent-dialog").empty().html(referentTemplate).dialog('open');
        }
    });
});
```

Everything works very nice except for the fact that the form inputs does not contains the data that is returned from the server. I have checked the data coming back with fiddler and it contains right values like this

```
{"d":"{\"ReferentID\":-1,\"LastName\":\"Abbot\",\"FirstName\":\"John\",\"FullName\":null,\"PhoneNumber\":null,\"Email\":null}"}
```

Where I am doing wrong?

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently your website returns a JSON object containing only one key `d` which contains a JSON string.

So you need to use `var referent = JSON.parse(msg.d);` or (which would be better) return proper JSON.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. On the server side I am just creating a new object with default values (for test) and using JavaScriptSerializer class to format it as JSON. Could you please give me more info on how to format properly a JSON result?

Comment: I don't know anything about .NET JSON builders. You should simply try to make sure your server sends a single JSON object and not a JSON string inside a JSON Object.

Answer (score 1):

You can place the `[ScriptService]` attribute on your class and then just return your object directly from your WebMethod rather than trying to do the serialization yourself.

Some reference:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.services.scriptserviceattribute.aspx

http://www.joe-stevens.com/2010/01/04/using-jquery-to-make-ajax-calls-to-an-asmx-web-service-using-asp-net/

Answer (score 1):

The [WebMethod] should be returning your JSON correctly.  You might want to try this:

```
        $("#new-referent").click(function () {
            $.ajax({ type: "POST",
                url: baseUrl + 'MyService.asmx/New',
                data: JSON.stringify({}),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                beforeSend: function (xhr) { xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8"); },
                success: function (msg) {
                    $('#referent-dialog').html('');
                    $('#referentTemplate').tmpl(msg.d).appendTo('#referent-dialog');
                    $('#referent-dialog').dialog('open');
                }
            });
        });
```